# Understanding Recursion using flow of control through recursion calls for Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, merge

I am studying the flow of control using recursion in Merge Sort.

The particular algorithm I used is:

```
MergeS(ar, p, r){

 1. if p<r{
 2.    k = floor[(p+r)/2]
 3.    MergeS(ar, p , k)
 4.    MergeS(ar, k+1, r) //in the schematic diagram I have written this as mergeS(,,)
 5.    Merge(ar, p ,k, r)
 6. } 
 7.}

Merge(ar, p, k, r){

 8.  n1 = k-p+1
 9.  n2 = r-p
 10. let L[1...n1+1] and R[1....n2+1] be new arrays

 11. for i=1 to n1
 12.   L[i] = ar[p+i-1]

 13. for j=1 to n2
 14.   R[j] = ar[k+j]

 15. L[n1+1] = Infinity
 16. R[n2+1] = Infinity

 17. i = 1
 18. j = 1

 19. for t = p to r
 20.   if L[i] <= R[j]
 21.     A[t] = L[i]
 22.     i = i+1
 23.   else
 24.     A[t] = R[j]
 25.     j = j+1
 30. }
```

**`MergeS(ar, k+1, r)` is exactly same as `merge(ar, k+1, r)`. I used the lowercase `m` in the latter only for better visual clarity in the schematic diagram**.

For understanding purpose, I took an array example-- **43, 32, 56, 12, 4**.

The flow of recursion calls is schematically shown below till the first call to Merge is made and the code inside that block is executed.

---1:**MergeS(ar, 0, 5)**-----

```
if(0<5):true ; set k=(0+5)/2
```

---Pause 1:**MergeS(ar, 0, 5)**-----Call-->2:**MergeS(ar, 0, 2)**---------

```
if(0<2):true ; set k=(0+2)/2
```

---Pause 2:**MergeS(ar, 0, 2)**-----Call-->3:**MergeS(ar, 0, 1)**---------

```
if(0<1):true ; set k=(0+1)/2
```

---Pause 3:**MergeS(ar, 0, 1)**-----Call-->4:**MergeS(ar, 0, 0)**---------

```
if(0<0):false
```

---Resume 3:**MergeS(ar, 0, 1)**-----Call-->5:**mergeS(ar, 0+1, 5)**---------

```
if(1<5):true ; set k=(1+5)/2
```

---Pause 5:**mergeS(ar, 0+1, 5)**-----Call-->6:**MergeS(ar, 1, 3)**---------

```
if(1<3):true ; set k=(1+3)/2
```

---Pause 6:**MergeS(ar, 1, 3)**-----Call-->7:**MergeS(ar, 1, 2)**---------

```
if(1<2):true ; set k=(1+2)/2
```

---Pause 7:**MergeS(ar, 1, 2)**-----Call-->8:**MergeS(ar, 1, 1)**---------

```
if(1<1):false
```

---Resume 7:**MergeS(ar, 1, 2)**------Call-->9:**mergeS(ar, 1+1, 5)**---------

```
if(2<5):true ; set k=(2+5)/2
```

---Pause 9:**mergeS(ar, 2, 5)**--------Call-->10:**Merge(ar, 2, 3)**---------

```
if(2<3):true ; set k=(2+3)/2
```

---Pause 10:**Merge(ar, 2, 3)**-------Call-->11:**Merge(ar, 2, 2)**----------

```
if(2<2):false
```

---Resume 10:**MergeS(ar, 2, 3)**-----Call-->12:**mergeS(ar, 2+1, 5)**----------

```
if(3<5):true ; set k=(3+5)/2
```

---Pause 12:**mergeS(ar, 2+1, 5)**------Call-->13:**MergeS(ar, 5, 5 )**---------

```
if(5<5):false
```

---Resume 12:**mergeS(ar, 2+1, 5)**-------Call-->**Merge(ar, 3, 4, 5)**----------

```
n1 = 4-3+1=2
n2 = 5-4=1

for(i = 0 to i=1):
  iteration1: 
    L[0] = ar[3+0-1]= ar[2] //value 56 is assigned to ar[2]
  iteration2:
    L[1] = ar[3+1-1] = ar[3] //value 12 is assigned to ar[3]

for(j=0 to j=0):
  iteration1:
    R[0] = ar[4+0] = ar[4] //value 4 is assigned to ar[4]

x = 0;
y = 0;

for(t=0 to t=1):
  iteration1: 
   /* if(L[0]<= R[0]) //56<=4:false */
   else
     ar[0] = R[0] //4 is assigned to ar[0]
     y = y+1
  iteration2:
   if(L[0]<=R[1]): //56<=infinity
     ar[1] = L[0] // 56 is assigned to ar[1]
```

After the preceding step, I got a value `4` in `ar[0]` and a value `56` in `ar[2]`. My guess is that this is wrong.

I need help understanding where I went wrong and and an explanation for that.

Comment: The displayed flow of recursive calls shows indicies that start at 0, but the psuedo-code shows indices that start at 1. It might be simpler to use p = starting index and r = ending index (1 past last element of array). The two MergeS recursive calls would be MergeS(ar, p, k), and MergeS(ar, k, r)  ... (k instead of k+1)  .

Comment: If I take MergeS(ar, k, r) then the middle index element will unnecessarily get copied more than once(when a call is made to the right part of the division) in each recursive call. 
If you could check the arguments that I have passed in each call and verify whether they are correct or not? If not, at what call did I feed the wrong  args.

Comment: Assume that r is the ending index in MergeS(ar, p, r), then a C based loop for the entire array would be for(i = 0; i < r; i++) ...   The terminating condition is < not <=.  So MergeS(ar, p, k) handles elements [0 ... k), and MergeS(ar, k, r) handles elements [k ... r), where [ means starting index, and ) means ending index (1 + last index). This is the way merge sort is usually implemented. Quick sort is the main exception where a last index is often used instead of an ending index.

Comment: Ok, got your point. You and I basically differ in terminating condition(I assume <=). I will analyse it once again with '<' and try to understand the flow of control. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices in the algorithm in the question need to be modified in the code for simpler use. I am not saying that the algorithm is wrong, it's absolutely correct, only needs modification.

The tweaked code of `Merge`:

```
 private static void Merge(int[] ar, int p, int k, int r) {

    int n1 = k-p+1;
    int n2 = r-k;
    int[] L = new int[n1+1];
    int[] R = new int[n2+1];

    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
        L[i] = ar[p+i]; // p+i and not p+i-1
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){ 
        R[i] = ar[k+i+1]; //k+1+i and not k+i
    }

    // Use of Tnteger.MAX_VALUE
    L[n1]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    R[n2]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(int t=p; t<=r; t++){ //carefully set initialization and t<=r and not simply t<r
        if(L[i]<r[j]){
            ar[t] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{

              ar[t] = R[j];
              j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The correct flow of recursion calls is shown below:(*the changes from the above flow of control diagram are italicised*)

---1:**MergeS(ar, 0, 5)**-----

```
if(0<5):true ; set k=(0+5)/2
```

---Pause 1:**MergeS(ar, 0, 5)**-----Call-->2:**MergeS(ar, 0, 2)**---------

```
if(0<2):true ; set k=(0+2)/2
```

---Pause 2:**MergeS(ar, 0, 2)**-----Call-->3:**MergeS(ar, 0, 1)**---------

```
if(0<1):true ; set k=(0+1)/2
```

---Pause 3:**MergeS(ar, 0, 1)**-----Call-->4:**MergeS(ar, 0, 0)**---------

```
if(0<0):false
```

---*Break 4:**MergeS(ar, 0, 0)***-----Call-->5:**mergeS(ar, 0+1, *1*)**---------

```
if(1<_1_):_false_ ;
```

---*Break 5:**mergeS(ar, 0+1, 1)**-----Call-->Merge(ar,0,0,1)*

After the execution of `Merge` function with parameters `ar, 0, 0, 1`, the elements at first two indices of the array **`43 32 56 12 4`** are swapped.

**Maintaining a stack of function calls came in handy.**